# Python File Tree + Size and countering number of files and directories

Tags: python, python-3.x

I currently have this:

```
import os

def list_files(startpath):
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(startpath):
        level = root.replace(startpath, '').count(os.sep)
        indent = ' ' * 4 * (level)
        print("F"+'{}{}/'.format(indent, os.path.basename(root)))
        subindent = ' ' * 4 * (level + 1)
        for f in files:
            print("D"+'{}{}'.format(subindent, f))
list_files('.')
```

The problem is now that I need to do this:
Make an executable Python script which prints a file tree as follows:

D or F [Filename/Directoryname] [Filesize/countfilesindirectory]

I only need to add this one, but I do not know how:
the file size or number of files in the directory

What I do want to improve it that you also can choose the location by yourself by before executing asking for input with

```
location = input("Location: ")
```

This location should get scanned for those directories recursively and show them in a tree.
If someone could help me that would be very useful!

Thanks in advance

~Blackd00r

Comment: Where is the question? What did you try? What are your progress?

Comment: ```import os
def tree_printer(root):
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(root):
        for d in dirs:
            print ("D"+os.path.join(root, d))     
        for f in files:
            print ("F"+os.path.join(root, f))
tree_printer('.')```

Answer (score 0):

This solution to the problem is:

I have added a counter for the file and the directories which start both at 0. In the forloop we add the length of the dir so the total can be calculated.

**print("{} files in {} folders".format(filecount, dircount))**

```
import os
def list_files(startpath):
    dircount = 0
    filecount = 0
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(startpath):
        dircount += len(dirs)
        filecount += len(files)
        level = root.replace(startpath, '').count(os.sep)
        indent = ' ' * 4 * (level)
        print("D"+'{}{}/'.format(indent, os.path.basename(root)))
        subindent = ' ' * 4 * (level + 1)
        for f in files:
            path = os.path.join(root, f)
            size = os.stat(path).st_size
            print("F"+'{}{} ({} bytes)'.format(subindent, f, size))
    print("{} files in {} folders".format(filecount, dircount))

list_files('.')
```